# Round off and round down the time

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and i need to figure out a solution in python that can round off a time > 30 minutes to 'next minute and 00 seconds' and time < 30 minutes to 'previous minute and 00 seconds'. I tried several approaches like converting time in minutes to timedelta type and subtracting it from another variable containing same minutes but it didn't work. 
I also applied some of the techniques mentioned in some other relevant questions but it didn't work. The time is already converted to datetime format through pd.to_datetime command.

Here is a sample data:

```
df name: Order_data  
column_name: Only_time

11:10:40  
09:13:26  
21:29:50  
19:13:37  
21:09:15  
19:51:43  
08:55:57  
13:31:01  
18:21:16
```

Comment: do you mean `> 30 minutes` or `> 30 seconds` ? Show what results you expect for your data.

Comment: I mean >30 minutes. Your mentioned code worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you want to convert for `> 30 seconds`, not `minutes`.

---

**EDIT:** using `dt.round()` woth `60S` or `T`

```
 df['Only_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Only_time'])

 df['rounded'] = df['Only_time'].dt.round('60S')
 df['rounded'] = df['Only_time'].dt.round('T')
```

Doc: [pandas.DatetimeIndex.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html) and [timeseries offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)

---

**OLD:** It is primitive method.

I convert string to integer values, make calculations, and convert values back to string

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Only_time'] = '''11:10:40
09:13:26
21:29:50
19:13:37
21:09:15
19:51:43
08:55:57
13:31:01
18:21:16'''.split('\n')

def round_time(text):
    hours   = int(text[:2])
    minutes = int(text[3:-3])
    seconds = int(text[-2:])

    if seconds < 30:
        seconds = 00                  
    else:
        seconds = 00
        minutes += 1
        if minutes == 60:
            hours += 1
            minutes = 00

    return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)

df['rounded'] = df['Only_time'].apply(round_time)

print(df)
```

Result

```
  Only_time   rounded
0  11:10:40  11:11:00
1  09:13:26  09:13:00
2  21:29:50  21:30:00
3  19:13:37  19:14:00
4  21:09:15  21:09:00
5  19:51:43  19:52:00
6  08:55:57  08:56:00
7  13:31:01  13:31:00
8  18:21:16  18:21:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_minutes(x):
  offset = 1 if x.second>30 else 0
  return x.replace(minute=x.minute+offset, second=0)

df['Only_time'] = df['Only_time'].apply(round_minutes)
```